# Online store for pies - Part 2: User authentication

Tags: javascript, html, angular.js, authentication, firebase

I'm building an angular application using AngularJS and AngularFire. As this is the second part of this "series" it might be a good idea to also check out [part 1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/78874/57087) to gain an even better overview of the register/login process.

I have a few concerns here:

- It feels like I shouldn't need to have a `$scope.loggedIn` variable in order to tell the site that a user is logged in. What's the proper way of doing this? I've seen the use of `authData` but I'm not quite sure how to use it.
- The second case in the switch doesn't ever get run because if there is an invalid email format, an error gets thrown instead of showing the error message. If I remove the `throw error` a user will be logged in even if the information is incorrect because the `.then` function gets run. This is also connected to the previous issue with the `$scope.loggedIn`, this variable isn't connected to AngularFire in any way and therefore the authentication process is **severely** broken. What would be the proper way of going about this matter?

Let me know if there is anything else worth pointing out.

The login template:

```
<div id="login-form-wrapper" class="rounded-corners box-shadow">
    <h1>Existing user</h1>
    <form method="post" id="login" name="login" novalidate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="email">Email:</label></td>
                <td><input type="email" ng-model="authInfo.email" alt="Enter your email" placeholder="Email" 
                           id="email" class="input rounded-corners box-shadow"></td>
                <td><span>*</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="password">Password:</label></td>
                <td><input type="password" ng-model="authInfo.password" alt="Enter your password"
                           placeholder="Password" id="password" class="input rounded-corners box-shadow"></td>
                <td><span>*</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <div class="error-wrapper">
        <h5 ng-repeat="error in errors" class="error" ng-bind="error"></h5>
        <h5 ng-show="isSuccessful" class="success" ng-bind="success"></h5>
    </div>
    <div id="form-btn-wrapper">
        <input type="button" form="login" name="login-submit" value="Login" 
               id="login-submit" class="btn" ng-click="authenticateUser()">
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller attached to the template:

```
pieShopApp.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$firebase', '$firebaseAuth', '$location', '$timeout', function ($scope, $rootScope, $firebase, $firebaseAuth, $location, $timeout) {

    $rootScope.loggedIn = false;

    $scope.ref = new Firebase ('https://<dbnamegoeshere>.firebaseio.com');
    $scope.syncAuth = $firebaseAuth($scope.ref);

    $scope.errors = [];
    $scope.isSuccessful = false;

    //Needs to be initialized in order for the
    //authentication to run properly
    $scope.authInfo = {};
    $scope.authInfo.email = "";
    $scope.authInfo.password = "";

    $scope.authenticateUser = function() {

        $scope.errors = [];

        if ($scope.authInfo.email === '' || $scope.authInfo.password === '') {
            $scope.errors.push('You must fill in both email and password.');

            return false;
        }

        $scope.syncAuth.$authWithPassword({
            email: $scope.authInfo.email,
            password: $scope.authInfo.password
        }).catch(function(error) {

            switch (error.code) {

                case 'INVALID_USER': $scope.errors.push('The email you have entered is not a registered user.'); 
                                    break;

                case 'INVALID_EMAIL': $scope.errors.push('Invalid email format.'); 
                                    break;

                case 'INVALID_PASSWORD': $scope.errors.push('Invalid password.'); 
                                    break;
            }

            throw error;
        })
        .then(function(authData) {
            $scope.isSuccessful = true;
            $scope.success = 'You have successfully logged in - Redirecting...';
            $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
            $timeout($scope.redirectUser, 3000);
        });
    }
    $scope.redirectUser = function() {
        $location.path('/pies');
    }
}]);
```